# Undefined Method - 'model name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error on the form below:
NoMethodError in Admin::Users#index
undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:Class

This form is on the Index Page. Any ideas I am getting this error?

Form:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
<div class="modal-footer">                              
    <%= form_for(@user, :url => admin_user_inactive_path(user.id), html: { "role" => "form" } ) do |f| %> # Error is occurring here...
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Inactivate User</button>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Users Controller:

```
def index
   @user = User.where(del_flag: false).order('last_name DESC')
end
...
def inactive
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @user.update_attribute(:inactive, true)
        flash[:success] = "The account (" + @user.first_name + " " + @user.last_name + ") has been inactivated."
        redirect_to action: :index
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Comment: your @user variable is a ActiveRecord::Relation, not a single instance of User. \

Comment: I think you have an error admin_user_inactive_path(user.id) should be admin_user_inactive_path(@user.id) also add User.where(...).order(..).first

Comment: I have modified the code above to include the `<% @user.each do |user| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your form to use local variable `user`, that contains single `User` object, instead of instance `@user` that contains `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
<%= form_for(user, :url => admin_user_inactive_path(user.id), html: { "role" => "form" } ) do |f| %>
```

etc.

I would also advice you to rename `@user` instance variable to `@users`, since singular form suggest that variable contains single `ActiveRecord` object.

Answer (score 1):

@user must be a particular instance of an user, not many users

`@user = User.where(del_flag: false).order('last_name DESC')` are many users. You could append a `.first` but i don't know if that is what you want to do

Comment: There is `<% @user.each do |user| %>` at the start of the code. I should have included that in the original.

Comment: than use ```<%= form_for(user...``` without the @

Answer (score 0):

i have two concern first you are using `form_for(@user)` this is a array not object . second `admin_user_inactive_path(user.id)` should use `@user.first.id` as `user` is not required. so use form_for(@user.first)